Remove the empty line in else statement
<<if $pass2 is false>>[[Passage 1]]<</if>>
<<if $pass1 is false>>[[Passage 2]]<<else>> want this line to disappear and take no space<</if>>
This is demo line should go up when the 2nd statement else statement is executed.

In above code I want my demo line to go up when the else statement is executed
I have tried /n, <<nobr>><</nobr>>, <<!-- -->> but nothing works
I am getting output like this only when the else statement is executed
Passage 1

This is demo line should go up when the 2nd statement else statement is executed.

but I want output like this
Passage 1
This is demo line should go up when the 2nd statement else statement is executed.

